# Хранение сессий в бд. php

Tags: php

Всем привет!

Делаю оплату в интернет-магазине, задача состоит в том чтобы сделать автоматическую оплату, т.е. пользователь перевел деньги (на пример через API яндекс денег) и если все хорошо в этот же момент юзер должен получить свои товары, http-уведомления в помощь. 
На сайте есть корзина, основанная на сессиях, как можно сохранить сессию в бд для того чтобы файл-обработчик http-уведомлений добавил необходимые товары?

Comment: Ну, если абстрактно - создаете табличку товары, и пишите туда сессию + ид товара, которые есть в корзине.

Comment: Дело в том, что в сессии хранятся не только одни товары, помимо этого там есть и другие данные.

Comment: Хотелось бы сохранить сессию в бд целиком, в таком виде как в php

Comment: Если нужно хранить другие данные, храните их в базе в json формате, например.

Comment: А зачем если у вас к примеру не используются вебсокеты и пользователь увидит только обновив страницу? А для этого проще и удобнее хранить товары с привязкой к пользователю по идентификатору, который можно получить с помощью ключа в сессии.

Comment: всю корзину лучше сохранить в БД, перед тем как отправлять пользователя к оплате. У пользователя может перезагрузится не вовремя компьютер или вообще сломаться и до его сессии вы никогда уже не доберетесь, он зайдет из другой сессии и должен увидеть весь набранный товар.

Comment: @Mike, это если есть авторизация. Но и если нету, статистика покупателей остановившихся с полной корзиной на оплате может быть весьма полезной.

Comment: @vp_arth Причем тут авторизация. Идет оплата через яндекс. что бы магазин узнал о том что именно было оплачено он должен сгенерировать уникальный ID и передать его в данных платежа яндексу, он же возвращается от яндекса обратно в оповещении о прохождении платежа. И вот за этим уникальным ID и надо сохранить набранные товары перед тем как отправлять запрос на яндекс. Назовем этот номер - номером заказа. А привязывать его к зарегистрированному пользователю или нет, это уже на усмотрение приложения. но заранее дать возможность клиенту после оплаты в случае сбоя как то добраться до заказа надо

Comment: @Mike, этот уникальный ID не стоит делать ключевым, если только вы не подписали эксклюзивный контракт с ЯД... Биллинговые вещи таки лучше хранить отдельно от самой корзины, имхо.

Comment: @vp_arth Не понял причем тут какие то контракты. ЯД просто передает сквозь себя этот ID, никак его не модифицируя. Это заявлено протоколом и это выполняется. И кстати в момент оплаты корзины никакой уже быть на должно, есть заказ, оплату которого мы ожидаем, мы же должны точно знать за что получили деньги. А что бы это знать, надо где то это сохранить и явно не в сессиях, которые еще пойди найди по информации от яндекса

Comment: Существуют платёжные гейты, кроме Яндекса

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая штука как Local Storage. Работает во всех браузерах. Почитать можно тут [Local Storage](https://tproger.ru/articles/localstorage/)  Используйте его, что бы не нагружать базу данных пользовательскими данными, особенно временными.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение этого вопроса, данные сессий в бд можно хранить в формате json , а затем просто раскодировать в php, спасибо пользователю [ArchDemon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/31819/archdemon), я как то об этом и не подумал.